# How can I use Expect to inline parse a line into multiple variables?

Tags: parsing, tcl, expect

I'm trying to parse a single line of text that looks like this:

```
Blah blah A=1234 B=5678 C=9999 blah blah
```

I want to populate three vars, A B and C, with the values from that line.

Ideally I would like to use an expect script that looks something like this pseudocode:

file.exp:

```
expect {
    "*A=" $A " B=" $B " C=" $C " *\r\n"
}
```

Obviously this will not run, but you can see what I'm trying to do.  I know I could do something like the code below, but it's a lot of typing and not as readable:

```
expect {
    * {
        set line split $expect_out(buffer) " "
        set A lindex (split (lindex $line 3) "=") 1
        set B lindex (split (lindex $line 4) "=") 1
        set C lindex (split (lindex $line 5) "=") 1
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I believe that Tcl's scan command does the trick :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tcl's "scan" command works just like sscanf:

```
expect * {
    scan $expect_out(buffer) "A=%i B=%i C=%i" A B C
}
```

Comment: The problem with that is that it won't match if there's anything extra at the start of the match space. You'd have to check that the `scan` returned a `3` (the expected number of filled fields) before deciding whether it is successful, but a more precise pattern would be simpler.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't know what your variables names are called, then this is very generic:

```
expect {
    -re {(\w+)=(\S+)} {
        lappend variables $expect_out(1,string)
        set $expect_out(1,string) $expect_out(2,string)
        exp_continue
    }
    eof
}
foreach varname $variables {puts "$varname=[set $varname]"}
```

You should alter the `eof` condition as appropriate -- that expect block will fall into an infinite-ish loop (depending on your timeout value) without an appropriate exit condition.

Also, my regular expression won't work for values with whitespace, e.g. `X="a string"`. Obviously this depends on what you expect to encounter.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to do it:

```
expect -re {^.*A=(\d+)\s+B=(\d+)\s+C=(\d+).*$} {
    set A $expect_out(1,string)
    set B $expect_out(2,string)
    set C $expect_out(3,string)
    # Do something with $a, $b, and $c
}
```

The `-re` flag tells expect to use regular expression, and parse the result into `$expect_out(1,string)`, ...